# mjpeg streaming in wpf not working

Tags: wpf

I develop a WPF app for mjpg streaming. I include the code here

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   MjpegDecoder _mjpeg;
   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      _mjpeg = new MjpegDecoder();
      _mjpeg.FrameReady += _mjpeg_FrameReady;
   }

   void _mjpeg_FrameReady(object sender, FrameReadyEventArgs e)
   {
      // What to write to get BitmapImage  
   }

   private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      _mjpeg.ParseStream(new Uri("http://155.41.145.37/mjpg/video.mjpg")); 
   }      
}
```

What I need to write to get the bitmap from the `frameReadyEventArgs` and how to assign that bitmap to a WPF `Image` control

Answer (score 1):

I've never used MJPEG Decoder library but if you go to their WPF [example](http://mjpeg.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MJPEG/MjpegProcessorTestWPF/MainWindow.xaml.cs) you'll find this:

```
private void mjpeg_FrameReady(object sender, FrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
   image.Source = e.BitmapImage;
}
```

`FrameReadyEventArgs` should already have `BitmapImage`

```
public class FrameReadyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
   ...
   public BitmapImage BitmapImage;
}
```